# VBA Excel - Adding together certain cell totals, performing calc, returning result in a merged cell

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I have 4 columns: Customer | Order No. | Pallets | Trucks Required

Each customer can have many Orders, and each Order can have many pallets.  I am trying to work out the number of trucks required (by dividing the total of all the pallets for all orders per customer by 8).  The tricky part is that i need to merge the cells of 'Trucks Required' by however many orders there are.  So for example:

**Order No. - Order No. - Pallets - Trucks Required**

Customer1 - Order1 - 3 Pallets

Customer1 - Order2 - 12 Pallets - 3  (This is merged with the above and below cells)

Customer1 - Order4 - 2 Pallets

Customer2 - Order7 - 11 Pallets

Customer2 - Order9 - 1 Pallets   - 3 (This is merged with the above and below cells)

Customer2 - Order3 - 6 Pallets

I have experimented with using a pivot table, but it doesn't appear to be possible to achieve my 3rd point.  I figure the best way to do this would be to use VBA, but i cant seem to find a good way of doing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see that you have merged the cells by Customer number i.e. Customer1 & Customer2 -- 3 orders respectively. Why cant this be done with Pivot & Calculated Fields ?

Comment: Its a formatting thing...  The Trucks required column show line items (and a subtotal if you wanted to show per Customer.  But its impossible to remove the line items in a pivot, so for example it would show the below in the truck required column: 0.375, 1.5, 0.25.  And then it would subtotal at the bottom.  It just looks a bit messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem

Before you run this macro you must select a cell in the table you want to "fix". something important you must know is that there is not cnrt-z after a macro runs so save your file before testing this.

```
Sub fixtable()

Dim obj As Range
Dim RangetoFix As Range
Dim Palletes As Integer

Set RangetoFix = Selection.CurrentRegion
Set obj = RangetoFix.Cells(2, 1)

Palletes = RangetoFix.Cells(2, 3).Value

For i = 3 To RangetoFix.Rows.Count + 1
    If RangetoFix.Cells(i, 1).Value = obj.Value Then
        Palletes = Palletes + RangetoFix.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Else
        Cells(obj.Row, obj.Column + 3).Value = Palletes / 8
        Range(Cells(obj.Row, obj.Column + 3), RangetoFix.Cells(i - 1, 4)).Merge
        Set obj = RangetoFix.Cells(i, 1)
        Palletes = RangetoFix.Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic, worked perfectly.  The only thing i changed was to round the value of 'Trucks Required' up to the nearest whole number using Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp().